# Conditional columns based on values in other columns in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a SQL that aggregates the monthly ticketing of different organisations to give an output like this -

| Organization | Course | Month | Last Updated | Status | Tickets This Month | Total Tickets | Deleted Tickets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OrgABC | C1 | 03/23 | 2023-07-21 | ACTIVE | 12 | 12 |  |
| OrgABC | C2 | 03/23 | 2023-04-19 | ACTIVE | 4 | 4 |  |
| OrgABC | C1 | 04/23 | 2023-07-21 | ACTIVE | 3 | 15 |  |
| OrgABC | C2 | 04/23 | 2023-04-19 | DELETED | 2 | 6 |  |
| OrgABC | C2 | 05/23 | 2023-04-19 | DELETED | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| OrgABC | C1 | 05/23 | 2023-07-21 | ACTIVE | 2 | 17 |  |
| OrgABC | C1 | 06/23 | 2023-07-21 | ACTIVE | 3 | 20 |  |
| OrgXYZ | C2 | 06/23 | 2023-08-15 | ACTIVE | 5 | 5 |  |
| OrgXYZ | C2 | 07/23 | 2023-08-15 | ACTIVE | 3 | 8 |  |
| OrgABC | C1 | 07/23 | 2023-07-21 | DELETED | 0 | 20 |  |
| OrgABC | C1 | 08/23 | 2023-07-21 | DELETED | 0 | 0 | 20 |
| OrgXYZ | C2 | 08/23 | 2023-08-15 | DELETED | 2 | 7 |  |
| OrgXYZ | C2 | 09/23 | 2023-08-15 | DELETED | 0 | 0 | 7 |

At this stage, I only have up till the `Tickets This Month` column in my query. The `Total Tickets` column aggregates the running sum of all tickets for an organization and course, whereas the running sum gets converted to `Deleted Tickets` if the status becomes 'DELETED'. What can I do to add two columns like `Total Tickets` and `Deleted Tickets` above where the logic is -

```
IF status = 'DELETED' and last_updated < billing_month
THEN convert total_tickets TO deleted_tickets AND make total_tickets = 0
ELSE total_tickets = total (prev_month) + tickets (current_month) AND deleted_tickets = 0
```

so that my table looks like the above table. Can you help me make these two columns please?

Comment: You want to reprocess shown data? can you please add the desired output?